# How do I save my child records from the parent controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a bunch of 'kid' objects saved already and I want to create a parent object which is linked to the kids via a 'relative' model.

This object gives me a many-to-many, through relatives.

To be clear: the user visits the 'parents' page, clicks create parents and is presented with a form that lets them name the parent and add up to four children to this parent (by creating 'relatives'), each of these 'relations' is also named - that's an important part. So, I could name the relation 'step son' or 'son', for instance.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
class Kid < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relatives
  has_many :parents, through: :relatives
end


class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relatives
  has_many :kids, through: :relatives

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :relatives,
    :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? },
    :allow_destroy => true
end


class Relative < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  belongs_to :kid
end



class ParentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_parent, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :lookup_kids, only: [:new, :edit]

  # GET /parents
  # GET /parents.json
  def index
    @parents = Parent.all
  end

  # GET /parents/1
  # GET /parents/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /parents/new
  def new    
    @parent = Parent.new
    4.times { @parent.relatives.build }
  end

  # GET /parents/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /parents
  # POST /parents.json
  def create
    @parent = Parent.new(parent_params)        

    parent_params[:relatives_attributes].each do |k,r|
      @parent.relatives.build(r.except(:_destroy))
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @parent.save
        format.html { redirect_to @parent, notice: 'Parent was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @parent }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @parent.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # cut for brevity.



  private

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_parent
      @parent = Parent.find(params[:id])
    end


    def parent_params
      params.require(:parent).permit(:name,
       relatives_attributes: [:parent_id, :kid_id, :relationship, :_destroy])
    end
    def lookup_kids
      @kids = Kid.all #for this nursery.
    end
end





<%= form_for(@parent) do |f| %>
  <% if @parent.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@parent.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this parent from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>

      <% @parent.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <h4>Kids:</h4>
  <%= f.fields_for :relatives do |r| %>
    <%= r.label :kid %>
    <%= r.collection_select :kid_id,
      @kids, :id, :name, include_blank: true%>
    <%= r.label :relationship %>
    <%= r.text_field :relationship %>    
    <%= r.check_box :_destroy %>
    <%= r.label :_destroy, "Remove" %>
    <br/>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>



ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151030113634) do
  create_table "kids", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
  create_table "parents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
  create_table "relatives", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "relationship"
    t.integer  "parent_id"
    t.integer  "kid_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end
  add_index "relatives", ["kid_id"], name: "index_relatives_on_kid_id"
  add_index "relatives", ["parent_id"], name: "index_relatives_on_parent_id"
end
```

When I get to 'create' in the parents controller, I can see the right parameters are getting through but the relationship records aren't being saved. SHouldn't this happen automatically?

I've tried looping through the :relatives_attributes but that doesn't seem to work with 'build'.

How am I suppsed to get the 'relatives' records to save?

EDIT: adding parameters posted:

```
parent"=>{
  "name"=>"Dad",
  "relatives_attributes"=>{
     "0"=>{"kid_id"=>"2", "relationship"=>"Son", "_destroy"=>"0"},
     "1"=>{"kid_id"=>"", "relationship"=>"", "_destroy"=>"0"},
     "2"=>{"kid_id"=>"", "relationship"=>"", "_destroy"=>"0"},
     "3"=>{"kid_id"=>"", "relationship"=>"", "_destroy"=>"0"}}}
```

**Edit: I've updated this to show my latest edit - note the 'parent_params[:relatives_attributes].each do |k,r|' in the controller. This now saves the kid records but the only problem is, it also saves the fields that are blank! So I have 'relative' records with null values for kid records. How can I stop it saving empty fields (or creating empty relative records)?**

Comment: Please remove the `parent_params[:relatives_attributes].each ...` stuff from the create action. After that check the console if you get a `COMMIT` or a `ROLLBACK` on save. If you had a rollback just add `puts @parent.errors.full_messages.inspect` before render the error, and check the console. If you had a commit check your console for `unpermitted attributes` (but I think it is right and you will not found this).

Comment: It commits. There are no unpermitted parameter warnings on the console. However, it doesn't save the 'relatives' on the parent (I checked the record in the rails console).

Comment: D'oh I read the title `How do I save my child records from the parent controller?` and thought this was from another stackexchange site where a parent is asking about their child's records at school or kindergarden!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was to build each sub-record of relative, like so:

```
parent_params[:relatives_attributes].each do |k,r|
  @parent.relatives.build(r.except(:_destroy))
end
```

Before calling @parent.save.

However, I'm still having issues getting rid of the blank records. So if anyone has an answer to that problem, please comment here - or if there's a better or more traditional way of doing this, hit me up. Follow up question here: [Why is this reject_if in my model not rejecting blank records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669179/why-is-this-validation-code-not-working-on-my-model)

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, depending upon how your form submission is, you most likely need an accepts_nested_attribute_for in your Relative associative class as well:

```
class Relative
  belongs_to :parent
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :parent
  belongs_to :kid 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :kid
end
```

If this doesn't work, then please submit your params that are passed into the controller and we can adjust accordingly

Comment: Like I said, I already have a bunch of 'kid' objects saved already' - so I don't need to add accepts_nested for kid on Relative. I'm creating the Relative within the parents controller, so I don't need accepts_nested for parent either - it works the other way around (relative's data in included in the post to parents controller, nested). I'll add the parameters posted to the controller in the question above. Thanks.

Comment: Just to be thorough though, I did try this and it didn't change anything. None of the 'kid' records got saved. Note in the example above, only one kid is being filled in for the parent. This is deliberate - it should ignore the blanks.