# Why is this reject_if in my model not rejecting blank records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the following class...

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relatives
  has_many :kids, through: :relatives

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :relatives,
    :reject_if => lambda { |a| a['kid_id'].blank? },
    :allow_destroy => true
end
```

...I've added some code which I expected to prevent 'relatives' from saving on the parent model if their fields were blank. It doesn't seem to work. It saved both blank and non-blank fields.

I.e. when I go into the console and query the database, I can pull out the parent record and run queries like so:

```
2.2.2 :004 > p.relatives.find(17)
  Relative Load (5.4ms)  SELECT  "relatives".* FROM "relatives" WHERE "relatives"."parent_id" = ? AND "relatives"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["parent_id", 24], ["id", 17]]     
 => #<Relative id: 17, relationship: "yes", parent_id: 24, kid_id: 1, created_at: "2015-11-12 09:56:07", updated_at: "2015-11-12 09:56:07">
```

That's what I expected - I entered data for that 'kid'.

```
2.2.2 :005 > r = p.relatives.find(18)
  Relative Load (3.4ms)  SELECT  "relatives".* FROM "relatives" WHERE "relatives"."parent_id" = ? AND "relatives"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["parent_id", 24], ["id", 18]]
 => #<Relative id: 18, relationship: "", parent_id: 24, kid_id: nil, created_at: "2015-11-12 09:56:07", updated_at: "2015-11-12 09:56:07">
```

This record should never have saved because it violates the lambda above, i.e. ...

```
2.2.2 :006 > r.relationship.blank?
 => true 
2.2.2 :007 > r.kid.blank?
 => true
```

...the fields are blank!

Here's the controller in question (extract):

```
class ParentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_parent, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :lookup_kids, only: [:new, :edit]

  # GET /parents/new
  def new    
    @parent = Parent.new
    4.times { @parent.relatives.build }
  end


  # POST /parents
  # POST /parents.json
  def create
    logger.debug(" SANITY CHECK ")
    logger.debug(parent_params)

    @parent = Parent.new(parent_params)    
    parent_params[:relatives_attributes].each do |k,r|         
     @parent.relatives.build(r.except(:_destroy))
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @parent.save
        format.html { redirect_to @parent, notice: 'Parent was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @parent }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @parent.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_parent
      @parent = Parent.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def parent_params
      params.require(:parent).permit(:name,
       relatives_attributes: [:parent_id, :kid_id, :relationship, :_destroy])
    end

    def lookup_kids
      @kids = Kid.all
    end
end
```

Comment: Could you fix your question to remove the html escapes?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I don't know who suggested that edit but it didn't help.

Comment: How is the bad relative being created?

Comment: Good question. I'll post the bit in the create method of the controller and it should be more obvious what it's doing. As to why it's doing it, I assume because the reject_if blank? isn't rejecting blank entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might help

https://fabianosoriani.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/accepts_nested_attributes_for-3-0-5-reject_if-still-have-gotchas/

There are some gotchas behind `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with validations.

Comment: 12th Nov 2015 as you asked. I have answered the question hopefully. Thanks for accepting

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding since model kid is associated by Relative, you should do like this. Try this in your Parent Model

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :relatives, :allow_destroy => true
```

Then in Your Relative Model,

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :kids,
    :reject_if => lambda { |a| a['kid_id'].blank? },
    :allow_destroy => true
```

Comment: I don't need to accept nested attributes for kids unless I want to build the kids from the parent form. The kids already exist. I know what I have already populates the relatives model. That's not the issue. The problem is that blank records are getting added to the relatives table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user5554692, discovered the only way to do this is as follows:

Adding this to the parent controller:

```
parent_params[:relatives_attributes].delete_if { |k,v| v['kid_id'].blank?}
```

Removed all blank records, then...

```
@parent = Parent.new(parent_params)
```

Creates the parent object as usual.

Apparently, reject_if just doesn't work in this particular scenario, for some reason.